# Session not remember, and why the session created each time I load the page?

Tags: session, laravel-5

I start to work with my project using laravel 5. I realized that it work fine in my local directory with session after I login to my site, But I just know that I got problem when I hosted my project to server. After I login each time, the session could not remember and recreated each time I loan the page. That cause the problem to me.

**Laravel Login**

```
public function postLogin(){
$hit = 0;
if(Request::ajax()){
    $pw = Request::input('pw');
    if(!empty($pw)){
        $admin_pass = AdminPassword::first(['admin_pass']);
        $ip_address = Request::ip();
        if(!empty($admin_pass) && trim($admin_pass->admin_pass) == trim($pw)){
            if(Auth::attempt(['username' => Request::input('username'), 'password' => Request::input('password'),'status'=>1])){
                try{
                    $user = Auth::user();
                    $user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $user->login_ip = $ip_address;
                    $user->save();
                    $permissions = Auth::user()->permission;
                    if(!empty($permissions) && count($permissions) >0){
                        session(['ROLE_PERMISSION'=>$permissions]);
                    }
                    $failed = FailedLogin::whereRaw('ip_address = INET_ATON(\''.$ip_address.'\')')->first();
                    if(!empty($failed)){
                        $failed->delete();
                    }
                }catch (\Exception $ex){}
                $url = Request::session()->pull('url.intended', '/');
                return ['url'=>$url,'msg'=>'Successfully.','status'=>true,'hit'=>$hit];
            }else{
                $hit = $this->updateFailedLogin($ip_address,Request::input('username'));
            }
        }else{
            $hit = $this->updateFailedLogin($ip_address,Request::input('username'));
        }
    }
}else{
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
return ['url'=>'','msg'=>'Try again.','status'=>false,'hit'=>$hit];
```

}

Please help me out. This is the final step of my project.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: In your .env file, what do you have `SESSION_DRIVER` set to?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have `SESSION_DRIVER` in your .env set to `file` - depending on your hosting environment, this could mean that your session isn't persisting due to each request being served from a different file server (common in cloud environments).

Try changing your `SESSION_DRIVER` to `database`.

Answer (score -1):

Did you put the

```
session_start();
```

in all your pages?
If not it might be your problem, I d suggest you to add this in your index directly

Comment: Excuse me guy, Could you detail me how?

Comment: I don't know how laravel 5 is working, but in php when the session restart, it means that you goes on a page which has not the session started. In many framework the session is automatically initiated but sometimes we go to a page out of the framework for some reasons and we loose the connexion due to that. It might be the problem.